# How to load tables in subreports in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-code, crystal-reports

I have this Crystal Reports report, I have this report with 7 subreports, one for every day of week, and these already load, but I would like to apply a filter so that only certain records are shown (aside from so that the report loads without requesting a database password).

This is my report
[This is my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDp9i.png)

This is my subreport, is a subreport
[This is my subreport, is a subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttNRl.png)

Use this option to create the subreports
[Use this option to create the subreports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4dgX.png)

```
private void ConsultarCheckOperation(string Miku, int Mode)
        {
            try
            {
                //This is other Report, this is Report 1
                Reporteador.ConsultaSP s = new Reporteador.ConsultaSP();
                DataSet Ds = s.CheckOp(Miku, Mode);
                RptCheckOperation RDOC = new RptCheckOperation();
                RDOC.SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);

                FormCheckOperation ChO = new FormCheckOperation();
                ChO.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RDOC;
                


                if (activeForm != null)
                    activeForm.Close();
                activeForm = ChO;
                ChO.TopLevel = false;
                ChO.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                ChO.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                panel4.Controls.Add(ChO);
                ChO.BringToFront();
                ChO.Show();


                //This is report 2, where I have the problem, but I put the first one, because that is where I make the call to the table, yes, I use the same DataSet to load 2 reports, I don't know if that is a problem

                DateTime Cartman = DateTime.Now;

                int Kenny;
                Kenny = Cartman.Year;

                Reporteador.ConsultaSP R = new Reporteador.ConsultaSP();
                DataSet Dr = R.SelectDate(1);
                Sanae RDOCA = new Sanae();
                RDOCA.SetParameterValue("Year", Kenny);


                RDOCA.Load("Subreport21");
                RDOCA.Subreports[0].DataSourceConnections.Clear();
                RDOCA.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);

                /*
                

                RDOCA.Subreports["Mon"].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports["Tues"].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports["Weds"].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports["Thurs"].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports["Fri"].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);
                RDOCA.Subreports["Sat"].SetDataSource(Ds.Tables[0]);*/

                FormProMes Ch1 = new FormProMes();
                Ch1.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RDOCA;



                if (activeForma != null)
                    activeForma.Close();
                activeForma = Ch1;
                Ch1.TopLevel = false;
                Ch1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                Ch1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                panel3.Controls.Add(Ch1);
                Ch1.BringToFront();
                Ch1.Show();

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }
        }
    
    
     //This is my DataSet

     public DataSet CheckOp(string Jo, int Accion)
        {
            var ConnectionString = conexionP.ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand Con = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SELECTCHECKOP]", sql))
                {
                    Con.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Con.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CheckOp", Jo));
                    Con.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Accion", Accion));
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Con);
                    sql.Open();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
                
            }
        }


   //Finally this is my StoreProcedure
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECTCHECKOP]
    @CheckOp varchar(40),
    @Accion int
   AS
   BEGIN
    if @Accion = 1
    begin
        select * from viewcheckoperation where [N° de OT (secundario)] = @CheckOp order by      Assembly_Level asc, [N° de OT (secundario)] asc, Sequence asc
    end

    if @Accion = 2
    begin
        select * from viewcheckoperation where [N° de OT Primario] = @CheckOp order by Assembly_Level asc, [N° de OT (secundario)] asc, Sequence asc
    end
    END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFw81.png)